# which package is advisable to implemet Oauth for stripe connect in meteor. Any example demos out there?

Tags: meteor, stripe-connect

I am looking to implememt stripe connect in meteor. I understand that the first step is to able to link the user account to platform accout. I believ this is done via the Oauth process. I am aware of this package( https://github.com/chadokruse/meteor-accounts-stripe-connect)
I am getting a type error "Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined" for the following code.

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: 'stripe',
  appId: Meteor.settings.client_id,
  secret: Meteor.settings.stripe,
  scope: 'read_write', //or read_only
});
```

Any other way for going about this without the package?

Comment: Follow up: Just realsised that the package has been flagged by atmostphere. So I need an alternate package in implementing this.

Comment: Asking for tutorials, packages or off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please check the [help/on-topic] and address your question via an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-saas-with-meteor-stripe-part-1/), you can use mrgalaxy:stripe.  You might be getting that error you're seeing because you haven't added the service-configuration package.  Do `meteor add service-configuration`.

Comment: I dont think mrgalaxy:stripe deals with the Oauth flow. I kind of need the Oauth flow so that customers can create a stripe account if they dont have one.